# Passing file paths to a batch file

Tags: c#, batch-file, xcopy

I'm calling a .bat file to XCOPY a folder. Is there anyway to pass the file name and the destination into the batch file?

My .bat file

```
XCOPY %1 %2
pause
```

The code I'm using to call the .bat is this:

```
process.Start(@"C:\Documents and Settings\cmolloy\My Documents\Test\XCOPY.bat");
```

I've tried this code

```
process.Start(@"C:\Documents and Settings\cmolloy\My Documents\Test\XCOPY.bat" , copyfrom copyto);
```

As i've used that before for shutting down my comp, but it doesn't work with this.

Thanks

**Update**

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Documents and Settings\cmolloy\My Documents\Test\XCOPY.bat";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = copyFrom.ToString();
process.StartInfo.Arguments = copyTo.ToString();
process.Start();
```

That is the code I'm using but It doesn't work. I'm getting this from the XCOPY screen:
[image]

So it doesn't look like its taking the full file paths. copyto and copyfrom are variables that contain the paths.

**UPDATE**

Using azhrei's code:

```
String batch = @"C:\Documents and Settings\cmolloy\My Documents\Test\XCOPY.bat";
String src = @"C:\Tricky File Path\Is Here\test1.txt";
String dst = @"C:\And\Goes Here\test2.txt";  
String batchCmd = String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\"", batch, src, dst);

process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/k \"echo {0}\"", batchCmd);

process.Start();
```

I'm getting this output:
[image]

Which isn't actually copying the file.

Comment: I typed this in Google: pass arguments to batch file

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Arguments` property

```
Process proce = new Process();
proce.StartInfo.FileName = "yourfile.exe";
proce.StartInfo.Arguments =  ..;
proce.Start();
```

Article : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jawedmd/xcopy-using-C-Sharp-to-copy-filesfolders/

Comment: Do i need to edit my .bat file to use this. Its currently only one line, `XCOPY copyfrom copyto` should I change it to `XCOPY %1 %2`? Thanks

Comment: Ok ELSheep0 i treat your question

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't pass the full directory to the batch file.

Comment: From testing it, I changed the batch to XCOPY "%1" "%2", it seems to be spliting the copyFrom path into different arguements, as when I ran it it returned, "C:\Documents" "and"

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with this,

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Documents and Settings\cmolloy\My Documents\Test\XCOPY.bat";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = // my arguments
process.Start();
```

A better option would be to replace what your XCOPY.BAT file is doing with the equivalent calls in `System.IO` (you get error handling then).

Comment: Do i need to edit my .bat file to use this. Its currently only one line, `XCOPY copyfrom copyto` should I change it to `XCOPY %1 %2`? Sorry thats its a complete copy of the other comment, but I just wanted to make sure you see it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're starting a batch file - you'll need to use `cmd.exe`

Surround each argument with `"` (needed if the argument has spaces).

```
  String batch = @"C:\Documents and Settings\cmolloy\My Documents\Test\XCOPY.bat";
  String src = @"C:\Tricky File Path\Is Here\test1.txt";
  String dst = @"C:\And\Goes Here\test2.txt";  
  String batchCmd = String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\"", batch, src, dst);

  process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
  process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/k \"{0}\"", batchCmd);

  process.Start();
```

If your batch file literally xcopies and nothing else, then you can just replace `cmd.exe` with `xcopy.exe` and remove the `/k + batch`.

Comment: That's an argument to `cmd.exe` to keep the window open, so you can see how the operation went. Or you can use `/c` instead, to close the window after the command finishes

Comment: I've updated the solution to handle spaces in your file paths (xcopy.bat and the copyfrom and copyto)

Comment: But src and dest both have to be the copyfrom and copyto variables, I pass the paths into them because they are changing. So src = copyfrom and dst = copyto. If that makes sence.

Comment: I've tried your code, but the batch tells me there are invalid number of parameters. And it seems to give me the date and time?

Comment: Ah yes, when passing in lots of quotes in arguments to `cmd.exe` you usually need an extra pair of quotes around the whole lot. I've edited the post to fix that bug. (And I have tested the code)

Comment: Its not copying the file, its just showing `XCOPY.bat path1 path2` but not copying.

Comment: That's what `echo ` does. Try it from the command prompt, `echo hello`. It's good for testing, so you know your command is going to get called properly. I've now edited the solution to get rid of the echo.

Comment: Getting rid of echo I get a invalid number of parameters?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15650/discussion-between-azhrei-and-elsheepo)

Answer (score 0):

Pass it parameters?

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true